# Fullcalendar : do a loop

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs

First sorry for my english, i'm french.

I have a weekly calendar. Only 7 days, no more. The calendar should make a loop. 
An event that start on the last day of the calendar must end on the first day of the calendar.

With an image it will be easier to explain my problem :
(You can see image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL4w5.jpg )

How that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question is too generic. What exactly do you need to know? It would help if you add a code sample that you currently are working on and where you are looking for the solution...

Comment: I just need an event that begins at the end of the week could be completed early that week .
My schedule I did not need the numbers of days or number of months. My planning to only need 7 days. When we reach the end of this planning, the event has to start early this schedule.